# SVG, how to evaluate the property of the svg object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am try to differential the object that created using `<path>` and using `<rect>`. I don't know how to access the their children property. I basically want to know if the object has such property. And in my code, I want to change the css style of both svg object when I click on the reset button. Thank you very much for the help.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // reset all the click
  $('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#displayWindow svg').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasOwnProperty('path'))
        $(this).children('path').css('fill', 'none');
      else if ($(this).children() == 'rect')
        $(this).children('rect').css('fill', 'none');
    }); // end each
  }); // end click
}); // end ready
```

```css
 #displayWindow {
   border: 1px solid;
   height: 600px;
   width: 800px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayWindow">
  <svg height="150" width="150" style="position:relative; left:5; top:5;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="blue" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
  <svg height="150" width="150" style="position:relative; left:5; top:5;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">2</text>
    <rect width="120" height="120" x="15" y="15" fill="blue" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
<br>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: If you want to change the style of both (and going by the code, set their fill to none) why do you need to differentiate? And even if you need to set different properties why not use direct selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you would like to "unfill" both svg objects, right? Then why not apply the attribute directly to both?..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // reset all the click
  $('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#displayWindow svg').find('path, rect').attr("fill","none");
  }); // end click
}); // end ready
```

```css
 #displayWindow {
   border: 1px solid;
   height: 600px;
   width: 800px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayWindow">
  <svg height="150" width="150" style="position:relative; left:5; top:5;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>
    <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="blue" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
  <svg height="150" width="150" style="position:relative; left:5; top:5;" class="ui-widget-content">
    <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">2</text>
    <rect width="120" height="120" x="15" y="15" fill="blue" stroke="blue">
  </svg>
</div>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
<br>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: What if I want to select the svg only within the div, such as I want to select the `<path>` or `<rect>` property only inside of the svg and inside of the display window, how do I select them? I am trying to do $('#displayWindow svg path, rect').attr("fill","none"); but it doesn't work. Thank you very much